# Spring Hibernate Native Query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Сформировал вот такой запрос:

```
 @Query(value = "WITH RECURSIVE r AS (\n" +
            "    WITH b AS (\n" +
            "        SELECT min(t.id) min,\n" +
            "               (\n" +
            "                   SELECT t.id\n" +
            "                   FROM initial_data AS t\n" +
            "                   WHERE vehicle_category_type = :categoryType\n" +
            "                   ORDER BY t.id DESC\n" +
            "                   LIMIT 1\n" +
            "                       OFFSET :col - 1\n" +
            "               )       max\n" +
            "        FROM initial_data AS t\n" +
            "        WHERE vehicle_category_type = :categoryType\n" +
            "    ) (\n" +
            "             SELECT id,\n" +
            "                    min,\n" +
            "                    max,\n" +
            "                    array []::bigint[] || id AS a,\n" +
            "                    0                        AS n\n" +
            "             FROM initial_data AS t,\n" +
            "                  b\n" +
            "             WHERE id >= min + ((max - min) * random())::int\n" +
            "               AND vehicle_category_type = :categoryType\n" +
            "             LIMIT 1\n" +
            "         )\n" +
            "    UNION ALL\n" +
            "    (\n" +
            "        SELECT t.id, min, max, a || t.id, r.n + 1 AS n\n" +
            "        FROM initial_data AS t,\n" +
            "             r\n" +
            "        WHERE t.id > min + ((max - min) * random())::int\n" +
            "          AND vehicle_category_type = :categoryType\n" +
            "          AND t.id <> all (a)\n" +
            "          AND r.n + 1 < :col\n" +
            "        LIMIT 1\n" +
            "    )\n" +
            ")\n" +
            "SELECT t.*\n" +
            "FROM initial_data AS t,\n" +
            "     r\n" +
            "WHERE r.id = t.id"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    List<InitialData> findRandomByVehicleCategoryType(String categoryType, int col);
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Синтаксическая ошибка в выражении SQL "..."; ожидалось "[, ::, AT, FORMAT, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, AS, ,, FROM, WHERE, GROUP, HAVING, WINDOW, QUALIFY, UNION, EXCEPT, MINUS, INTERSECT, ORDER, OFFSET, FETCH, LIMIT, SAMPLE_SIZE, FOR, )"
```

Хотя в консоли БД , запрос отрабатывает отлично.

Comment: Возможно, проблема в синтаксисе приведения типов. Попробуйте такую конструкцию: `CAST(value AS type)` вместо `value::type`. Плюс, возможно, стоит убрать переносы строк.

Comment: а почему не используете `@Param` ? метод должен выглядеть так: `findRandomByVehicleCategoryType(@Param("categoryType") String categoryType, @Param("col") int col);`

Comment: Основная проблема была в ембедед БД для тестов. Она то была Н2 и у нее есть проблема с рекурсивными запросами. Сменил на Postgres embedded и запрос стал проходить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб отдельное спасибо за подсказку с CAST. Когда сменил :: на CAST - сменилась формулировка ошибки, и далее уже методом исключения нашел проблемный оператор...

Comment: @MrFylypenko в spring-boot 2 это делать не обязательно, на эту тему есть хороший пост на хабре: https://habr.com/ru/post/440214/